# Pixel-perfect 2x (3x, 4x…) scaling of screen resolution

Tags: windows

There is a patch for XRandR utitily (on GNU/Linux OS) that allows to apply "nearest pixel" filtering to non-native screen resolutions, as described here:

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=159064

It allows to get each pixel of image (desktop) resolution displayed by a square made of 4 (2x2) pixels of TFT matrix for 2x scaling (for example 1920x1080 resolution on 3840x2160 monitor), or 9 (3x3), or 16 (4x4), etc. so that there is no blur at all despite seemingly non-native resolution.

Is there anything like that in windows world? (preferably for windows XP or 7 or 10)